# Android, Gradle: Set testBuildType by buildType name

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

My build.gradle:

```
android {
    testBuildType "stage"
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        prod {
            // This copies the debuggable attribute and debug signing configurations.
            initWith(debug)
        }
        stage {
            initWith(debug)
            // some code here
        }
        dev {
            initWith(debug)
            // some code here
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I testBuildType as string. But I want set by **buildType.name**.

Something like this:

```
testBuildType buildType.stage
```

I get this error :

```
Error:(56, 0) Could not get unknown property 'stage' for BuildType container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The error answers your question - there is no such property, and I do not think you can achieve what you wanted here. But, why don't you explain what it is your need exactly, perhaps there are other ways.

Comment: I need to start instrumented unit test on android. If not set "testBuildType" to any buildType (in example "stage") then I get compile error: "Can not resolve symbol import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;"

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the testBuildType element in the buildTypes block

Comment: @sam_k I have this in my build.gradle file and it works. Please provide a reference if you think my answer is wrong before you downvote it

Comment: I would expect a detailed answers, not one liner. It would be better to comment there on a question post.